# How do i get databasevalues in my website by using a var?

Tags: php, mysql

We are doing a project using flipcards to show questions and flip over to see the answer. We have to use a database and we managed to get someone to add a category and the questions and answers into the database.

But now we want to get those questions and answers out of the database and place them on our flashcards. But we cant seem to get it right.

This is what we have :

Index.php

```
foreach($aCategories as $aCategory) {
                $name = $aCategory['id'];
                echo "<div class='col-md-3 col-xs-6'><a href='/oefenen/vraag-1' name='$name' class=\"btn btn-info\">".$aCategory['name']."</a></div>";
            }
```

Oefenen_Controller.php

```
public function IndexAction()
{
    $oDatabase = new Database();
    $this->userLoggedIn();

    $aCategories = $oDatabase->getCategories();
    $this->set("aCategories", $aCategories);

    $aVragen = $oDatabase->getVragen();
    $this->set("aVragen", $aVragen);

}
```

In the index.php we tried to use name='$name' to get the values out of the database, but that doesnt seem to work. On our cards it shows the hard coded questions we used as examples, but not the questions that we try to get out of the database.

Is there someone who understands our question and knows how to do this ? Or maybe can help us on our way ?

Comment: Can you provide a var_dump of `$aCategories` and `$aVragen` (or at least a sample of var_dump) to see what's inside and thus the name of your fields please ?

Comment: here did you hardcode a questions?

Comment: make sure the $aCategory['id']; is set

Comment: Like this?
<?php
            foreach($aCategories as $aCategory) {
                $name = $aCategory['id'];
                echo "<div class='col-md-3 col-xs-6'><a href='/oefenen/vraag-1' name='$name' class=\"btn btn-info\">".$aCategory['name']."</a> 
                var_dump($name);</div>";

            }
            var_dump($aCategory);
            var_dump($aVragen);
            ?>